# Заставить DateTimePicker1 не прятать календарь после выбора даты

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Есть *DateTimePicker1*, при выборе не правильной даты в *DateTimePicker1*, я вывожу в (*DateTimePicker1Change*) некое сообщение, и хочу, чтоб после этого календарь не прятался.

Строка:

```
SendMessage(datetimepicker1.Handle,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_F4,0);
```

Позволяет показать календарь. Но в совокупности с событием «DateTimePicker1Change» эта строка не работает. Вообщем она там и не должна работать.

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Change(Sender: TObject);
const
{$J+}
  D: TDate = 0.0;
{$J-}
var
  d1, d2: TDate;
begin
  d1 := StrToDate('20.07.2017');
  d2 := StrToDate('25.07.2017');
  if DateTimePicker1.Date <> D then
  begin
    D := DateTimePicker1.Date;
    if d1 < d2 then
    begin
      showmessage('Правильно d2 старше чем d1');
      SendMessage(datetimepicker1.Handle,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_F4,0);
    end;  
  end;
end;
```

Как мне добиться желаемого результата?

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему - никак. Ну или тот же трюк с F4, который Вы и пытались реализовать:

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Test!');
  **DateTimePicker1.SetFocus;**
  SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F4, 0);
  **SendMessage(DateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_F4, 0);**
end;
```

P.S: Календарь закрывается потому что фокус уходит в окно сообщения. Поэтому после его закрытия необходимо вернуть фокус DateTimePicker'у.